# How to create a 2D pan which is scrollabe in any direction?

Tags: android, 2d

In Android Is it possible to create a big  2D `window` like 4 times bigger then the screen.

In this `window` there are many `Views` or `Fragments` and the User must use his finger to drag this `window` right, left, up down to get to a `View`.

Lets say the `Views` or `Fragments` represent a billboard with information. On `View` is a chat and another is maybe a list of stuff. The function is like the Google maps where you can drag the map around but instead drag my `window` around to interact with all the `Views` or `Fragments`

I have search and found this [AndroidTreeView](http://s://github.com/bmelnychuk/AndroidTreeView) that let me drag the `TreeView`  around like in 2D, very cool and maybe it can be modified.

The gole here is to instead of the Android `Navigationview` that the User must open and select something, I want to put the Navigationview items in this big 2D `window`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this link. There is a custom view that does what you want :

http://web.archive.org/web/20131020193237/http://blog.gorges.us/2010/06/android-two-dimensional-scrollview

Comment: wonderful, i see now that the  AndroidTreeView i mention is using it to